# RODBC sqlQuery() returning error messages on successful execution

Tags: r, rodbc

This is a bit of a time-sensitive/emergency problem. I have some R code that involves a number of SQL queries using the RODBC package. This code runs every morning on a dedicated Linux server - it pulls down some data, does some statistics, and inserts the data back into an MSSQL DB.

Today, our sysarch upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04.1, and since then, I'm having a bunch of problems with ODBC. After making a few changes, we got it so that ODBC connections can be established, but now there's an even bigger problem. Basically, I'm getting error messages from RODBC every time I do a CREATE or DROP command, even though the identified tables are created/dropped. Example (`bts.connect` is the result of `odbcConnect([connection information])`):

```
> sqlQuery(bts.connect, "SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tempscores')")
1 1050250967
```

So the #tempscores table exists

```
> sqlQuery(bts.connect, "DROP TABLE #tempscores")
[1] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'DROP TABLE #tempscores'"
```

Even though it exists, we “can’t” drop it

```
> sqlQuery(bts.connect, "SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tempscores')")
1 NA
```

But we have dropped it.

```
> sqlQuery(bts.connect, "CREATE TABLE #tempscores (dummy int)")
[1] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE #tempscores (dummy int)'"
```

We also can’t create it, but it exists and we can SELECT from it:

> sqlQuery(bts.connect, "SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tempscores')")
>      1 1066251024
>   sqlQuery(bts.connect, "SELECT * FROM #tempscores")
>       [1] dummy
>       <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

I'm at wits' end, and I really need this to run successfully tomorrow morning for a client. Anybody have any idea what could be causing this strange behavior?

Comment: Some of the "emergency" is done... I took out the part of my code that `stop()`'d if RODBC threw an error, and it ran to completion. This is clearly a terrible long-term solution, though...

Comment: Are you sure this is a problem with R/RODBC?  Have you tried these commands from another client (e.g. Squirrel)?  Did you try reinstalling R and/or RODBC?

Comment: I have done these same queries on the same connect string in MSSQL Server and isql - no issues. I've reinstalled R to no avail, and am just about to reinstall RODBC and likely dependent packages.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: Just reinstalled RODBC... no change, though.

Comment: What driver are you using to access MS SQL Server from linux?  Perhaps that needs to be reinstalled or rolled back?

Comment: Looks like FreeTDS version 7.0...
From /etc/freetds/freetds.conf: 
    [dbea01c]
    host = [correct host redacted]
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.0
From /etc/odbc.ini:
    [eadb]
    Driver = FreeTDS
    Description = Enterprise Analytics DB
    Trace = No
    Servername = dbea01c
    Database =

Comment: Also, isql is using the same connection and returns no errors for these commands.

Comment: Not sure how you reinstalled R/RODBC, but maybe some stray user settings remained and you need to purge/reinstall those.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm seeing the same error using temp tables with RODBC.

Comment: @krondor I'm afraid not... honestly don't even remember what ended up happening with that demo, ha. Sorry!